# trouble in using flalign (LaTeX)

Tags: latex

I am trying to put 3 equations with "=" signs aligned but also left aligned. I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
RPC &= A+B\tilde{f} +C x  &\\
A   &= a+\eta             &\\
E   &= cte                &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

With this I get the stuff in the left and the "=" signs aligned. However, I also need A (in the second equation) and E (in the third equation) to be aligned to the R (in the first one)

Does anyone know how to get it?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

This approach avoids explicit spacing commands.

```
\begin{flalign*}
RPC          &= A+B\tilde{f} +C x  &\\
\omit$A$\hfil&= a+\eta             &\\
\omit$E$\hfil&= cte                &
\end{flalign*}
```

This way is a little less TeXish.

```
\begin{flalign*}
\rlap{$RPC$}\phantom{RPC} &= A+B\tilde{f} +C x  &\\
\rlap{$A$  }\phantom{RPC} &= a+\eta             &\\
\rlap{$E$  }\phantom{RPC} &= cte                &
\end{flalign*}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all different combinations of `&`s and haven't found anything that works quite right.  There's probably some better way of doing it, but you could just use `\hphantom` to make the `A` and `E` take roughly the same amount of space as `RPC`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
RPC            & = A+B\tilde{f} +C x  \\
A\hphantom{PC} & = a+\eta \\
E\hphantom{PC} & = cte
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
\begin{flalign*}
& RPC &{}={}& A+B\tilde{f} +C x  &\\
& A   &{}={}& a+\eta             &\\
& E   &{}={}& cte                &
\end{flalign*}
```

Notes:
1. The {} around the equals sign are needed to give it something to space itself against.
2. In a flalign environment the fields alternately flush right and then flushleft. We can analyse one of the lines above using >>> and <<< to show the direction of flush

```
  & RPC & {}={} & A+B\tilde{f} +C x &     \\
>   <<<   >>>>>   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   >>>
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean there will be a large space between RPC and the rest of the equation?

Comment: "In a flalign environment the fields alternately flush right and then flushleft." --> THANK YOU! that was the missing piece in the puzzle to understand what was happening

Answer (score 0):

What follows is not elegant but it does the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0pt}
\begin{flalign*}
 & RPC & &\mspace{-22.0mu} = A+B\tilde{f} +C x  \\
 & A   & &\mspace{-22.0mu} = a+\eta             \\
 & E   & &\mspace{-22.0mu} = cte              

\end{flalign*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. This seems to produce somewhat good results:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
RPC\hphantom{AE}   & \mspace{-30.0mu}= A+B\tilde{f} +C x  & \\
A  \hphantom{RPCE} & \mspace{-30.0mu}= a+\eta             &\\
E  \hphantom{RPCA} & \mspace{-30.0mu}= cte                &
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```